# Как убрать пробел в конце вывода

Tags: c++, c

```
void print(string b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
        printf("%c ", b[i]);
}
```

Comment: if( i == b.size() - 1)    printf("%c", b[i]); else  printf("%c ", b[i]);

Comment: `if(b.size()){printf("%c", b[0]); for (int i = 1; i < b.size(); i++)        printf(" %c", b[i]);}`

Comment: Для счётчика лучше использовать тип `std::string::size_type`, тем более когда размер строки заранее не известен, как тут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void print(string b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
         if(i != b.size() - 1)
             printf("%c ", b[i]);
         else
             printf("%c", b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Лучше не делать сравнение в цикле, как у @AlexGlebe

Answer (score 2):

я бы сделал как-то так:

```cpp
if (str.empty() == false) {
  std::copy(str.begin(), --str.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<char>{std::cout, " "});
  std::cout << *str.rbegin();
}
```